# recurrent sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider a sequence ${u_n}$ defined by the recurrence relation:

$$u_n=\begin{cases}u_0 \in [0,1] & \\  \\  u_{n+1}=\dfrac{u_n^2}{2-u_n^2} & \end{cases} $$

Deduce that $ 0 \leq u_n <1$  then $(u_n )_{n\geq 0}$ is decreasing.

[This question is related to that one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1007804/study-of-a-function-on-interval-0-1/1007819#1007819)

Attempt:

let $u_{n+1}=f(u_n)$   since $x \in [0,1[,\ 0\leq f(x)\leq x <1.$ then $\ 0\leq f(u_n)\leq u_n <1$.
beside of that $\forall n,\quad u_{n+1}\leq u_n$ then $(u_n )_{n\geq 0}$ is decreasing.

Am i right ?

is there any other solution to that question ?

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 3):

Since $u^2$ is non-negative and monotonically increasing for $u\ge0$, and since $2-u$ is positive and monotonically decreasing for $u\lt2$,
$$
\frac{u^2}{2-u}
$$
is non-negative and monotonically increasing for $u\in[0,2)$. Furthermore, it increases from $0$ to $1$ on $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

Educ, you can study the function $f(x)=\frac{x^2}{2-x^2}$ in $[0,1]$:
$f'(x)=\frac{4x}{(2-x^2)^2}$, then $f\left([0,1]\right)\subset[0,1]$ (so $(u_n)$ is well defined) and $f$ is increasing (so $f$ is monotone).

By recurrence, $u_0\in[0,1]$ and $u_n\in[0,1]\Longrightarrow u_{n+1}=f(u_n)\in[0,1]$ (since, $f\left([0,1]\right)\subset[0,1]$).

$u_{n+1}-u_n=\frac{u_n^2}{2-u_n^2}-u_n=\frac{u_n}{2-u_n^2}\left(u_n-2+u_n^2\right)=\frac{u_n(u_n+2)}{2-u_n^2}(u_n-1)\leq0$

Answer (score 0):

$$0\leqslant x<1\Rightarrow 0\leqslant x^2<x<1\\2-x^2>1\\\frac{1}{2-x^2}<1\\\text{multiply by }x^2\\x^2\frac{1}{2-x^2}<x^2*1\\\frac{x^2}{2-x^2}<x^2< x <1\\now\\u_{n}=x$$

Comment: yes that's what you did in that last question but how can i deduce from that to say that $0\leq u_n<1$ and $u_n$ is decreasing

Comment: If $x=u_n$ then $\dfrac{x^2}{2-x^2} = u_{n+1} $. The answer above says $u_{n+1} < u_n^2 < u_n$